# Typescript Generic type makes compilation error

Tags: typescript, generics, compilation

I've got a case where i need to get a hierarchy between differents class of items. They all extend the same class ItemExt.

I'm using Typescript 2.4.2

Here is my Code :

```
export class ItemCollection<ItemFather extends ItemExt, ItemSon extends ItemExt> {

  constructor(private typeClass: { new (): ItemSon; }, parent? : ItemFather, fatherColl? : ItemCollection<ItemFather, ItemSon>){
  }

  public GetSub<ItemSon extends ItemExt, ItemSub extends ItemExt>(typeClass: { new (): ItemSub; }, obj : ItemSon) {
      return new ItemCollection<ItemSon, ItemSub>(typeClass, obj, this);
  }
}

export abstract class ItemExt {
  public Id : string;
}
```

But compiler give me an error in method "GetSub" on "this" :

> Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'ItemCollection'. Type 'ItemCollection' is not assignable to type 'ItemCollection'. Type 'ItemFather' is not assignable to type 'ItemSon'. Type
>   'ItemExt' is not assignable to type 'ItemSon'.

I think its just a Syntax or déclaration trouble because of when i use eval("this") insted of "this" It works as expected.

Could some one please help me to avoir compilation error without eval ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't name the thing `type`.  don't be like angular and confuse lots of people

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the type of `fatherColl` in the constructor is `ItemCollection<ItemFather, ItemSon>` and so when you call `new ItemCollection<ItemSon, ItemSub>(...` it is enforcing that the type of the third parameter be `ItemCollection<ItemSon, ItemSub>` since you have defined the types such that the generics on the incoming father colletion need to match the generics of the `ItemCollection` being created.

So essentially you are passing in `ItemCollection<ItemFather, ItemSon>` yet telling it it should be expecting type `ItemCollection<ItemSon, ItemSub>`.

These two definitions don't match up and thus it correctly says you have a type error.

The reason this works if you simply `eval` it is that typechecking like this is not part of Javascript and purely in the realm of TypeScript, and by putting everything in an `eval` call you are removing typechecking.

Comment: Thanks for your response, that's what i understand. So what sould I change to make il works without eval ?